# Team City VCS error collecting changes

Tags: svn, build, continuous-integration, teamcity

I am getting the following error on my TeamCity project:

```
Error collecting changes for VCS repository 'MySvnRepository'
Unable to get SVN log entries for: https://myserver/svn/trunk; range: 
RR[99_2013/08/27 13:35:20 +0100 => 6_2013/08/27 14:40:13 
+0100]@d2fecd1e-4276-d847-874c-cb6b9eafeb43; revisions: 99..6
```

I have tested the VCS connection through the "Test Connection" button in the TeamCity admin screen and it connects fine.

Looking at the error message it looks as though it is trying to retrieve entries 6 - 99, but there are only 6 log entries in the repository as it is newly created. I have checked that the build counter has been reset.

Is there something obvious I am missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We had faced similar issue with team city. Seems problem was some how it was trying to fetch the SVN logs from two configurations. Because we had used the same VCS root for 2 different branches at different times.

To solve this, delete and recreate the build configuration as well as the VCS root and it should work.

Comment: Also, take a look at comments for the issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-9967, especially regarding removal of `repositoryStates` directory.

Comment: I didn't have to delete the build configuration, just detach, delete, and recreate the VCS root and it worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why this worked for me, but I went into the VCS config and changed the SVN Client version from 1.6 to 1.7, and then everything started working.

Comment: We had migrated our SVN server and we begun receiving this error on TeamCity and had trouble getting rid of it.  We tried rebooting the box and whatnot.  The answer @Mike gave, for some reason, worked.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I talked with JetBrains support about this, and they said that this issue remains unresolved and reffered me to this:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-9967#comment=27-437160

TL;DR
Backup, and the delete the contents of this folder:
\system\pluginData

Answer (score 0):

This is old but something that comes up for me from time to time. The problem happens when you repoint an existing project at a different SVN root. If you look at the request TeamCity is making (99_2013/08/27 13:35:20 +0100 => 6_2013/08/27 14:40:13 +0100) you'll see it's trying to find the changes from revision 99 to 6 (which obviously there are none). The 99, I suspect, is the last revision before you re-pointed the SVN root of the project to the new one, that has 6 revisions in it. I have the same problem and yes, deleting the VCS root (not just detach) will fix this but that's not an option for anyone who's reusing a VCS root among many projects (like me). I don't know an option here, last time it happened to me I just checked in some bogus changes to get my repo to bump up to 1+ rev over what TeamCity was looking for, however today I'm facing this problem going from 2099 changes to 3. Maybe there's an SVN thing you can do but other than deleting the VCS root I don't know what to do on the TeamCity side. I've even deleted the project and created a new one, the problem lies in some cache TeamCity has for that repo and what the counters are at.